# Check if QLabel is enabled, pyqt label state (isEnabled)

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to check QLabels state and make an action over that control. I have a label and I want to use `isEnabled()` function on this label (or something like that function).

I try to use `isEnabled()` on label but it didn't work and I could not find any similar function.

```py
if self.myLabel.isEnabled():
    print("yes label is enabled")
else:
    print("label is disabled")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `self.myLabel.setDisabled(True)` then `self.myLabel.isEnabled()` should return False, but try: `self.myLabel.isVisible()`.

Comment: `isEnabled()` is working like you said. But I don't understand why it is not working without `setDisabled(True)`. When I create label I already make it disable. Why should i have to set disable again?` isVisible()` function is working but no matter it label is active or passive. If its visible it returns true.

Comment: I've never done it that way, I don't know how to help you I'm sorry. I usually build the window with QtDesigner and generate the python code then I set the widgets as disabled.

Comment: What do you man with "When I create label I already make it disable"? How and when do you disable it?